# Multiple Hashicorp Vault servers in different AZs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, high-availability, hashicorp-vault

I have 3 Availability Zones in my AWS VPC and I would like to run Vault to connect to S3. I would like to run 3 Vault servers (one for each zone) all of them syncing to the same S3 bucket. Is this HA scenario for Vault possible?

I read that Vault doesn't support HA using S3 as the backend and might need to use Consul (which runs 3 servers by default). A bit confused about this. All I want is to run multiple Vault servers all storing/reading secrets from the same S3 bucket.

Thanks for your inputs.

Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Storage Backends in Vault, and only some of them supports HA, like Consul. However, if a backend doesn't support HA it doesn't mean that it can't be used at all.

So, if you need to run multiple Vault istance, each one independent from the other ones, you should be able to use S3 as a Storage Backend. But if you need HA you need to use Consul, or any other backend that support HA.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for that answer. That helps.

Comment: You welcome. If that was the answer that you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

Note you could use DynamoDB to use an Amazon managed service & get HA support:

> High Availability – the DynamoDB storage backend supports high availability. Because DynamoDB uses the time on the Vault node to implement the session lifetimes on its locks, significant clock skew across Vault nodes could cause contention issues on the lock.

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/dynamodb.html